Speed issue while testing socketio using chrome's network throttling
I have a nodejs server that uses socketio. It also serves a static html page to the client that also uses socketio. I use it to test the speed of the socket connection (upload and download speeds). Without using chromes's network throttling it works fine and provides good speeds upon testing. But when I use the network throttling then it becomes super slow. The upload speed test works fine but the download speed is very very slow. For now I am testing with 150 Mbits/s download and upload speed from chrome's network tab. The upload speed is measured around 15MB/s which is okay but the download speed is 0.07-0.08 MB/s which is not supposed to be.
Also, if I use 6x CPU throttling then the download speed increases to 8-9MB/s. I don't know what I am doing wrong. I couldn't find any similar problem anywhere, neither any documentations.
Here is my code,
Server Code
const express = require( 'express' );
const http = require( 'http' );
const { Server } = require( 'socket.io' );
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer( app );
const io = new Server( server, {
    pingTimeout: 60000,
} );

app.get( '/', ( req, res ) => {
    res.sendFile( __dirname + '/index.html' );
} );
io.engine.on("connection", (rawSocket) => {
    rawSocket.request = null;
  });
io.on( 'connection', ( socket ) => {
    console.log( `A user connected with id: ${ socket.id }` );

    // Latency (Already implemented in earlier code)
    socket.on( 'ping', ( data ) => {
        console.log( `Latency: ${ 2 * ( Date.now() - data.startTime ) }` );
        socket.emit( 'pong', data );
    } );

    // Handle download test
    socket.on( 'startDownloadTest', () => {
        const totalSize = 50  * 1024 *1024; // 50 MB
        const payload = Buffer.alloc( totalSize, 'x' ); // Create a buffer with 5MB of data
        const chunkSize = 0.5*1024*1024; // 512 KB
        const chunkCount = Math.ceil( totalSize / chunkSize );
        let sentSize = 0;
        const startTime = Date.now();

        console.log( 'Download test started' );

        // Function to simulate sending data in chunks
        const sendChunk = ( index ) => {
            if ( index < chunkCount ) {
                // Emit the chunk data to the client
                const chunk = payload.slice( index * chunkSize, ( index + 1 ) * chunkSize );
                sentSize += chunk.length;

                socket.emit( 'downloadData', {
                    payload: chunk,
                    startTime,
                    totalSize,
                    sentSize,
                    progress: ( sentSize / totalSize ) * 100, // Calculate percentage
                } ,res=>{
                    console.log("Emitting packet"+index)
                    sendChunk( index + 1 )
                });

            } else {
                console.log( 'Download test completed' );
                socket.emit( 'downloadDataComplete', { message: 'Download test complete' ,endTime:Date.now()});
            }
        };

        // Start sending chunks
        sendChunk( 0 );
    } );
    let receivedData = '';
    socket.on('uploadChunk', (data) => {
        receivedData += data.chunk; // Append the received chunk

        console.log(`Received ${data.sent + data.chunk.length}/${data.totalSize} bytes`);

        if (receivedData.length === data.totalSize) {
            console.log('Upload complete');
        }
    });

    socket.on('uploadComplete', (data) => {
        const endTime = Date.now();
        const uploadTime = endTime - data.startTime;
        const uploadSpeed = ((data.totalSize/(1024*1024)) / (uploadTime /1000)).toFixed(2); // KB/ms -> MB/s

        console.log(`Upload complete: ${data.totalSize} bytes in ${uploadTime} ms`);
        console.log(`Average upload speed: ${uploadSpeed} MB/s`);

        // Clear the stored data
        receivedData = '';
        socket.emit('uploadResult', { uploadSpeed });
    });

    socket.on( 'disconnect', () => {
        console.log( 'A user disconnected' );
    } );
} );

server.listen( 3000, () => {
    console.log( 'Server listening on http://localhost:3000' );
} );


Client Code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Socket.IO Speed Test</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.6.1/socket.io.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Socket.IO Speed Test</h1>
    <p id="latency">Latency: Calculating...</p>
    <p id="download-speed">Download Speed: Calculating...</p>
    <p id="upload-speed">Download Speed: Calculating...</p>
    <p id="downloadProgress">Download Progress: 0%</p>

    <button id="testDownload">Test Download Speed</button>
    <button id="testUpload">Test Upload Speed</button>

    <script>

        const socket = io();
        const pingInterval = 1000; // Time in milliseconds between pings
        let startTime;
        // Latency Test
        function sendPing() {
            startTime = Date.now();
            socket.emit("ping", { startTime });
        }

        socket.on("pong", (data) => {
            const latency = Date.now() - data.startTime;
            document.getElementById("latency").innerText = `Latency: ${latency} ms`;
        });

        setInterval(sendPing, pingInterval);

        // Download Speed Test
        document.getElementById("testDownload").addEventListener("click", () => {
            socket.emit("startDownloadTest");
            document.getElementById("downloadProgress").innerText = `Download Progress: ${0}%`;
        });

        socket.on("downloadData", (data,callback) => {
            const { progress, sentSize, totalSize } = data;
            const downloadSpeed = (sentSize / (1024*1024)) / ((Date.now() - data.startTime) / 1000); // MB/s
            document.getElementById("download-speed").innerText = `Download Speed: ${downloadSpeed.toFixed(2)} MB/s`;
            document.getElementById("downloadProgress").innerText = `Download Progress: ${progress.toFixed(2)}%`;
            callback()
        });

        // Upload Speed Test
        document.getElementById("testUpload").addEventListener("click", () => {
    const totalSize = 50 * 1024 * 1024; // 50 MB
    const chunkSize = 0.5*1024*1024; // 512 KB
    const uploadData = "x".repeat(totalSize); // Create 5 MB string
    const uploadStart = Date.now();
    let sent = 0;

    const sendChunk = () => {
        if (sent < totalSize) {
            // Create a chunk from the full data
            const chunk = uploadData.slice(sent, sent + chunkSize);

            // Emit the chunk
            socket.emit("uploadChunk", {
                chunk,
                sent,
                totalSize,
                startTime: uploadStart,
            });

            sent += chunkSize; // Update the progress

            // Schedule the next chunk
            setTimeout(sendChunk, 10); // Adjust delay as needed for smoother transmission
        } else {
            // Signal completion to the server
            socket.emit("uploadComplete", { totalSize, startTime: uploadStart });
        }
    };

    sendChunk(); // Start sending chunks
});


        socket.on("uploadResult", (result) => {
            document.getElementById("upload-speed").innerText = `Upload Speed: ${result.uploadSpeed} MB/s`;
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>


Here is a screenshot of the network throttling settings,
Network Throttling Profile
I tried testing without the network throttling, it works fine. I tried testing with throttling, upload speed is okay but download speed is not.
If I use CPU throttling set to 6x then the download speed increases but the upload speed falls. Also, if I set the CPU throttling to 20x then everything becomes slow again.
